# How do you give style to the active state of a TextBox?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, styles

I know I can rewrite the Template of my TextBoxes to redefine it's visual states but isn't there an easy way to just say: "make this textbox yellow when it is active (got focus)"?

Something like "input:active" in css.

Maybe a way in silverlight to set the style to a visual state of a control instead of it's general look?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should make a `Style` which changes the `VisualState`.

See here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use VisualStates you can simply set a [FocusVisualStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.focusvisualstyle.aspx) directly on the TextBox.

```
<TextBox FocusVisualStyle={...} ... />
```

Or you can use a trigger in the normal style. In fact the documentation above suggests using a trigger can be a better approach:

> If you are intending control-specific behavior that is deliberately
>   not coherent across a theme, a much better approach is to use triggers
>   in styles for individual input state properties, such as **IsFocused** or
>   **IsKeyboardFocusWithin**,

A trigger is the closest thing to the css pseudo-class approach, unfortunately its not as succinct.

Comment: Note FocusVisualStyle is not for Silverlight (WP7).